# neo4j Cypher Grouping

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I have a database of tweet nodes and each tweet has a userId field with relationships based on if the tweet was replied to. I am trying to write a query where I group all of the tweets by user while preserving tweet relationships to see the relationship between users.

So far I have

match (n:Tweet) return  distinct(n.userId), n

but this does not work because the relationships are not preserved. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What is your data model? Show the nodes (and node labels), the relationship types, and how the nodes are connected by those relationship types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer in response to your comment.

So if you want to find out if users have had a conversation you might do:

```
MATCH (source_tweet:Tweet)<-[:REPLY_TO]-(reply_tweet:Tweet)
MATCH
  (source_user:User {userId: source_tweet.user}),
  (reply_user:User {userId: reply_tweet.user})
CREATE UNIQUE reply_user-[:REPLIED_TO]->(source_user)
```

Then you could do:

```
MATCH (user1)-[:REPLIED_TO]-(user2)
WHERE ID(user1) < ID(user2)
RETURN user1.userId, user2.user_id
```

... to get all of the combinations.

Though like I said, you should really have relationships between the tweets and users indicating which user made the tweet.  If you had that the query might be like:

```
MATCH (source_user:User)-[:WROTE]->(source_tweet:Tweet)<-[:REPLY_TO]-(reply_tweet:Tweet)<-[:WROTE]-(reply_user:User)
CREATE reply_user-[:REPLIED_TO]->(source_user)
```

And that should also be much faster because you're doing relationship traversals rather than looking up in the `userId` index.

Comment: The first query in your answer(MATCH (source_tweet:Tweet)<-[:REPLY_TO]-(reply_tweet:Tweet)...) References user nodes. Does this query assume that I have user nodes, or does the query create user nodes?

Comment: All of it assumes that you have `User` nodes.  If you don't you could probably just do `MATCH (source_tweet:Tweet)<-[:REPLY_TO]-(reply_tweet:Tweet) WHERE source_tweet.userId < reply_tweet.userId RETURN source_tweet.userId, reply_tweet.userId`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without creating a new [:Replied_To] relationship?

Comment: Probably, but it's probably not going to be ideally fast.  Do you have any relationships?  Why are you trying to avoid relationships?  Relationships are fundamental to how data is stored and queried in Neo4j....

Comment: The problem is I need to make a new query to form the relationships, and re-run this query every time a new user is added.

Comment: Can't you create the relationships as part of the process of inserting your tweets/users/whatever?  You can use the `MERGE` and `CREATE UNIQUE` clauses to make sure that you don't get duplicates

Comment: I am new to the cypher query language. Ideally, I would like to be able to the following in one query. 1. Create tweet. 2. Create User(if it does not already exist) and relate it to the tweet 3. If the tweet is a reply to another tweet relate it to that tweet(can not do without key value pairs) 4 if a user has replied to another user, relate thoes users. Is there a way to do this in one query?

Comment: You should be able to do the first three items in one query with a `CREATE` followed by one or more `MERGE` clauses.  You could probably do the last in the same query too, though why not two queries?  Either way, I'd make it a separate SO question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking...  You're talking about relationships but you haven't matched on any.

Speaking generally when you use an aggregate function (such as `sum`, `count`, `collect`, etc...) in a `RETURN` (or a `WITH`) clause Neo4j will automatically group by the other columns in the clause.  Here's an example of something that you might do:

```
MATCH (source_tweet:Tweet {userId: 1234})<-[:RETWEET_OF]-(retweet:Tweet)
RETURN source_tweet:Tweet.id, source_tweet:Tweet.text, count(retweet)
```

This will give you one line for each tweet userId #1234 has made and a count of the number of retweets for each of those tweets.

Comment: This is not what I was trying to do. In the database, I have many tweets that have the same userId parameter value(meaning that the same user tweeted  the tweet).  Currently my database has these long reply chains where one user replies to another, then the user replies back, and so on. All I really care about is that the two users are connected. I want to reduce the reply chain to simply two user nodes with one relationship between them.

Comment: That makes sense, though having a foreign key like that in Neo4j is a code smell, I would say.  I would create `User` objects with a `id` or `userId` property on them and have relationships between the tweet and the user.